# Expect Script for CLI

Tags: bash, highlight, expect

UPDATE: I am really frustrated at this point.  I've tried moving the expect code to its own file and calling it from the bash script.

```
...
if [[ "$okay" == "OK" ]]
then
    echo "PASSWORD ACCEPTED"
    echo "Modifying User Passwords..."
    COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt $num ]; do
             let index=COUNTER+1
             tmp=user_$index
             echo "Changing Password for " ${!tmp}
                 tmp2=$(${!tmp})
             echo $tmp2
             sh ./input.sh ${current_user} ${pass} ${password} ${tmp2}
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
...
```

input.sh

```
expect -f
#------------------------------------------------------
set current_user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set tmp2 [lindex $argv 3]

echo "EXPECT SCRIPT RUNNING"
sudo passwd ${!tmp2}
expect -exact "[sudo] password for $current_user: "
send "$pass\r"
expect -exact "New password: "
send "$password\r"
```

I would greatly, greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out.

---

I am writing a script that will allow a Linux admin to quickly change passwords of its users.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# Check password for strength 
# ----------------------------------------------
read -p "What's your username?" current_user
read -p "What's the root password?" pass
read -p "How many users?" num
COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt $num ]; do
         let index=COUNTER+1
             read -p "Enter username$index : " user_$index
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
read -p "Enter password : " password
echo 
echo "Tesing password strength..."
echo
result="$(cracklib-check <<<"$password")"
okay="$(awk -F': ' '{ print $2}' <<<"$result")"
if [[ "$okay" == "OK" ]]
then
    echo "PASSWORD ACCEPTED"
    echo "Modifying User Passwords..."
    COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt $num ]; do
             let index=COUNTER+1
             tmp=user_$index
             echo "Changing Password for " ${!tmp}
             echo ${!tmp}
             sudo passwd ${!tmp}
             expect -exact "[sudo] password for $current_user: "
             send "$pass\r"
             expect -exact "New password: "
             send "$password\r"
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done

    #echo "$user:$password" | usr/sbin/chpasswd
else
    echo "Your password was rejected - $result"
        echo "Try again."
fi
```

However, the expect portion, which would automate the inputting of passwords, is not highlighted in my editor and does not work.  I keep getting prompts to manually enter text.  This is especially surprising since the script is sourcing expect, not bash.  I've been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours.  Can anyone please lend me a hand?

Comment: I'm really frustrated at this point.  I've tried some new code where I make a new expect file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues in your code. At first, you have tried adding `#!/usr/bin/expect` in the code, which should throw you an error about the `read` command as,

```
wrong # args: should be "read channelId ?numChars?" or "read ?-nonewline? channelId"
    while executing
"read -p "What's your username?" current_user"
```

The reason is simply because the script will be treated as `Expect` script and it is not following it's syntax for `read`. I wonder how it worked for you. :)

When it is called as shell script, in that it should be enclosed withing `expect -c` not simply with `expect -f`

When `expect -c` is enclosed with single quotes, it won't allow bash substitutions. So, I am going to use double quotes. (but, it we have to escape the `Expect`'s double quotes with backslashes.)

```
admin="dinesh"
admin_pwd="root"
user="satheesh"
user_pwd="Hello@12E"
OUTPUT=$(expect -c "
        # To suppress any other form of output generated by spawned process
        log_user 0

        spawn sudo passwd $user
        expect {
                timeout { send_user \"Timeout happened\n\";exit 0}
                \"Sorry, try again\" {send_user \"Incorrect admin password\";exit 0}
                \"password for $admin: $\" {send \"$admin_pwd\r\";exp_continue}
                \"password: $\" {send \"$user_pwd\r\";exp_continue}
                \"successfully\" {send_user \"Success\"; exit 1}
        }
")
echo "Expect's return value  : $?"
echo "-----Expect's response-----"
echo $OUTPUT
```

The `Expect`'s return value will be available in the variable `$?`. This will help us to know whether the password update is successful or not. The variable `OUTPUT`, will have the output generated by spawned process.

Use the `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/usr/bin/expect`, since it is actually a bash script.